# Vue v3 Expected 'v-bind:key' directive to use the variables which are defined by the 'v-for' directive

Tags: vue.js

Edit: I fixed this error with parantheses, changing v-for to `v-for="(color, index) in global.base_colors"`

I'm working on my first Vue (v3) app, for learning purposes.

As a single page, using `Vue.createApp()`, it works fine, but I've been migrating it over.

I've been getting this error

```
for(let color, index in global.base_colors);
    |                      ^  vue/no-parsing-error
226:60  error  Expected 'v-bind:key' directive to use the variables which are defined by the 'v-for' directive
```

From this code

```
<span v-for="color, index in global.base_colors" v-bind:key="color">
  <input type="checkbox" :id="'inColor'+index" name="inColors" :value="color.toLowerCase()" class="gui"><label :for="'inColor'+index" :style="'border-left-color: '+color.toLowerCase()+'; background-color: '+color.toLowerCase()">{{color}}</label>
</span>
```

My `site.global.base_colors` a simple array of strings `['red','blue','green']`

Funnily enough, the code works. I can see behind the error-overlay that color-list is rendering.

When I google for this, I get pages instead for `Elements in iteration expect to have 'v-bind:key' directives`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this error with parantheses, changing v-for to `v-for="(color, index) in global.base_colors"`.